# How to use seperate scss files for each blade file

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-blade, vite

### Project setup

The project is laravel 10 setup with sail and thus using vite.
Also bootstrap 5 and bootstrap icons is added through npm.

### What I want to achieve

I am using blade components and I want each component to have its own scss file for styling.
I want the styling to be only loaded when using the component.

### What I want to know

Is it possible to use seperate scss files in my laravel project?
How do I tell laravel which scss file is for which blade file?

If its not possible to use scss files how can I achieve my goal with css files?

Where would I put the scss/css files in my project?
I read that when using vite you can put them in the resource folder and otherwise they should be in the public folder.

### What I have now

If I am missing files that are necessary for an answer please inform me.
I want this question to be understandable and usable for other users so thats why I try to include as little as possible of my own files.

**My vite config:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
            '~bootstrap-icons': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap-icons'),
        }
    }
});
```

**My package json:**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "sass": "^1.62.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5"
    }
}
```

**My folder structure:**

```
public/
└── build
resources/
├── js/
│   ├── app.js
│   └── bootstrap.js
├── scss/
│   ├── components/
│   │   └── form/
│   │       └── text-input.scss
│   └── app.scss
└── views/
    ├── auth/
    │   └── login.blade.php
    ├── components/
    │   └── form/
    │       └── text-input.blade.php
    └── layouts/
        └── authentication.blade.php
```

### What I have tried

I have tried to put the scss files in resources and public folder and reference them with @pushonce('mystack) in my blade view.
This is without success since the scss stays empty.

When adding my scss file to the app.js as import it is loaded but with a generic build name and loaded on every single page of the application, which im trying to avoid.

Comment: I never used blade template, but I don't think vite can help you on this one, you could easily include different style/script file in either vue/react pages template if you using front-end js. but I think you can accomplish the same thing with blade using `@stack`, or `@inject` or maybe `@push` on each blade file, checkout the [blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#stacks)

Comment: In this file `resources/scss/app.scss` include all your separate .scss files. Look at bootstrap, how they did it

Comment: @UnderDog I do not want all the styling to load on every page, I have updated my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Answer

I have found out that styling to be only loaded when using the view/component is not possible with Vite.
It is possible in laravel mix which is unfortunately deprecated but does solve my question.

## Solution

For the solution we will migrate to laravel mix and change a little of the setup.

### Migrate from vite to laravel mix

Follow the steps from here: https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix

### Npm packages

These packages have to be installed as dev dependencies:

- sass
- sass-loader
- glob
- resolve-url-loader

`sail npm install sass sass-loader glob resolve-url-loader --save-dev`
We need these packages to compile the scss files and add them automaticly to laravel mix.

If you also want the public directory to be cleaned each time when build add: `npm install rimraf --save-dev`.

### Update the webpackconfig

Change the extension from `webpack.mix.js` to `webpack.mix.cjs` if using ES module. 
Add this inside the `webpack.mix.cjs` file:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const glob = require('glob');
// Using rimraf for cleaning (optional)
const rimraf = require('rimraf');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

// Clean the "public/css" and "public/js" directories before each build (optional)
mix.before(() => {
    rimraf.sync('public/css');
    rimraf.sync('public/js');
});

// Loads all javascript files in resources/js and compiles them to public/js with the same directory structure
const jsFiles = glob.sync('resources/js/**/*.js');
for (const file of jsFiles) {
    const outputFilePath = file.replace(/^resources\/js/, 'public/js');
    mix.js(file, outputFilePath);
}

// Loads all scss files in resources/scss and compiles them to public/css with the same directory structure
const scssFiles = glob.sync('resources/scss/**/*.scss');
for (const file of scssFiles) {
    const outputFilePath = file.replace(/^resources\/scss/, 'public/css').replace(/\.scss$/, '.css');
    mix.sass(file, outputFilePath);
}
```

This will add javascript and scss files in your resources directory automaticly to laravel mix so its compiled to the public folder.
It also keeps the same directory structure.
When adding new files be sure to use `npm run dev` so they are compiled and watched by laravel mix.

## Usage

You now can use @push('styles') or @pushonce('styles') inside your blade files to load the styles/js only when the blade view is used.

### Example

Have in your root file (Layout):

```
<head>
  @stack('styles')
</head>
<body>
  @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

Now in the blade view you're using:

```
@pushOnce('scripts')
  <script src="{{ mix('js/myCustomFolder/myComponent.js') }}" defer></script>
@endPushOnce
@pushOnce('scripts')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/myCustomFolder/myComponent.css') }}">
@endPushOnce
```

I use pushOnce since I sometimes reuse components multiple times on a page and only want the styling and javascript to be loaded once.

### Npm webpack

Be sure to run webpack when using laravel with `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`. When adding new files you should rerun the command again.

### Pay attention for this

For this you write the styling in your **.scss** files in the `resource/scss/**` directory but when referencing it in the blade view you use the `public/css` directory with the **.css** extension.

Comment: I am very curious why you had this need, vite solves your issues, and be super very careful as Laravel mix is deprecated, so you are reverting to an already deprecated and not maintained anymore package, that is a massive no for a project that already has the new stuff.

Comment: My application will include many views/components with their own stylesheets. I want the styling to be in seperate files for clarity which is necessary because of the size. Now I don't want all the styles be loaded when they are not used, this is unneccesary data being transferred and increases the change of styling problems because of duplicate style names used. Vite doesn't support seperate stylesheets that are only loaded when the view is used.
I currently don't have more time to resolve this issue with Vite, which is easily solved in laravel mix. When possible in Vite I will migrate back.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve is easy to do with `@push` and `@stack` directives. The following assumes an older "Template Inheritance" style, but I've tested it to work with component approach as well, as long as you use the `@stack` directive in the layout.

In your layout:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @stack('styles')
</head>

<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

In your view file (auth/login.blade):

```php
@extends('authentication')

@section('content')
    <form>
        @include('text-input', ['name' => 'username'])

        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
@endsection

@push('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-vite-or-mix-call-here" />
@endpush
```

In your "component" file:

```php
<input type="text" class="text-input" name="{{$name}}" />

@push('styles')
    <style>
        .text-input {
            background-color: beige;
        }
    </style>
@endpush
```

The result is the rendered markup that includes the styles from both: your view file and any "components" down the line.